# TypeScript error File '/node_modules/detectincognitojs/dist/detectIncognito.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306) on npm package import

Tags: typescript, module, react-typescript, npm-package

I am trying to use an npm package called  [**detectincognitojs**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detectincognitojs)

I follow the instructions in its page and I try to import it

```
import { detectIncognito } from "detectincognitojs";
```

And I get an error:

```
File '/node_modules/detectincognitojs/dist/detectIncognito.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

This is the content of this file (detectIncognito.d.ts):

```
declare const detectIncognito: () => Promise<{
    isPrivate: boolean;
    browserName: string;
}>;
//# sourceMappingURL=detectIncognito.d.ts.map
```

I don't understand what's the problem here and whether I am doing something wrong. I just followed the developer's instructions.

**Edit:**

I am using create-react-app with the TypeScript template

I have also created a minimal reproducible example, an empty test project and when I tried to import it, I had the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the package was problematic in version 1.2.0. I contacted the developer and after an update to 1.3.0 it now works.

I am attaching the issue I opened for future reference:

[Error: File '/node_modules/detectincognitojs/dist/detectIncognito.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306) #29](https://github.com/Joe12387/detectIncognito/issues/29)